# Elasticsearch - specify different index and search analyzers for one field

Tags: elasticsearch, stringtokenizer

I want to let one field indexed by different analyzers `my_analyzer_1` and `my_analyzer_2`, looks like:

```
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_analyzer_1": {
          "type":"custom",
          "tokenizer": "keyword"
        },
        "my_analyzer_2": {
          "type":"custom",
          "tokenizer": "standard"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "Names": {
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "type": "string",
          // Is it possible?
          "analyzer": "my_analyzer_1, my_analyzer_2"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And when search, manually specify use `my_analyzer_1` or `my_analyzer_2`.

That means, for `fox brown`, search by term `fox`. When using `my_analyzer_1` will not get `fox brown` because `fox brown` is analyzed as one term due to [keyword](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-keyword-tokenizer.html) tokenizer. While using `my_analyzer_2` will get it because it is analyzed as 2 terms `fox` and `brown`.

Elasticsearch allows specify [search_analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-analyzer.html) and [index_analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-analyzer.html), but seems it only allows specify single search_analyzer and single index_analyzer.

Is my requirement possible by Elasticsearch?

(One workaround is to use 2 fields, one use `keyword` tokenizer and another use `standard` tokenizer)

Comment: `multifield` is an option for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
"name": {
    "type": "string",
    "fields": {
        "analyzed1":   { "type": "string", "analyzer": "analyzer1" },
        "analyzed2":   { "type": "string", "analyzer": "analyzer2" }
    }
}
```

You can then query on

```
`name.analyzed1` or `name.analyzed2`
```

depending on whether you want to query using `analyzer1` or `analyzer2`

Reference : 
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/_multi_fields.html

Comment: Nice answer! Also find if does not specify analyzer when search like query on `name`, it use default analyzer.

Comment: Yep.. .it uses standard analyzer then.